# Parsing JSON string from URL with Python 3.5.2

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the values `"lat"` and `"lon"` from the JSON ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=coordinates&list=&titles=venice)):

```js
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "normalized": [
            {
                "from": "venice",
                "to": "Venice"
            }
        ],
        "pages": {
            "32616": {
                "coordinates": [
                    {
                        "globe": "earth",
                        "lat": 45.4375,
                        "lon": 12.33583333,
                        "primary": ""
                    }
                ],
                "ns": 0,
                "pageid": 32616,
                "title": "Venice"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code that I supposed to work:

```
import urllib.request as url
import json
import urllib.parse
import ast

request = url.Request('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=coordinates&list=&titles=venice')
data = url.urlopen(request).read()
data = data.decode("utf-8")
data = ast.literal_eval(data)
data = json.dumps(data)
array = json.loads(data)
#print(array)
print(array['query']['pages']['32616']['coordinates']['lat'+','+'lon'])
```

It returns the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries somewhere. Can you show a *minimal* `array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(array['query']['pages']['32616']['coordinates'][0]['lat'])
print(array['query']['pages']['32616']['coordinates'][0]['lon'])
                                               insert ^
```

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake. didn't consider [0]! It works perfectly. but I faced another problem. I didn't consider the third value of my json document ['32616'] as a dynamic variable(it is page_id). Do you know "How can I deal with dynamic keys in Python 3x?

Comment: You could simply loop over the elements in `array['query']['pages']`, like so: `for key, value in array['query']['pages'].items():`. Then you can get `value['coordinates'][0]['lat']` and `['lon']`.

Comment: Thanx a lot, you have been really helpful. I don't know how can I give you stars as a plus point.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('you URL here')
rData = json.loads(r.text, encoding="utf-8")

print(rData['query']['pages']['32616']['coordinates'][0]['lat'])
print(rData['query']['pages']['32616']['coordinates'][0]['lon'])
```

Comment: You don't even need the `json` module, just use `r.json()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. but I faced to another problem. I didn't consider the third value of my json document ['32616'] as a dynamic variable(it is page_id). Do you know "How can I a parse JSON document with dynamic keys in Python 3x?"

Comment: for page in rData['query']['pages']: